# SQL Update unable to work

Tags: php, sql-update

I have a SQL update below and there's no error but it doesn't reflect any changes I have made to the database. I also paste here the 2 previous php which will lead to the update php. SQL query for UPDATE shows no error too.

Please let me know if i miss out anything.

Appreciate it very much.

table 1: nmc_cd

[image]

table 2: nmc_category

[image]

table 3: nmc_publisher

[image]

This is the php to display the list of CDs and the key here is the CDID which once selected will be sent to the next php.

```
include 'database_conn.php';    //make db connection

    $sql = "SELECT nmc_cd.CDID, nmc_cd.CDTitle, nmc_cd.CDYear, nmc_cd.CDPrice, nmc_category.catDesc, nmc_cd.catID
                FROM nmc_cd 
                LEFT JOIN nmc_category ON nmc_cd.catID=nmc_category.catID"; 

    $queryresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
    or die (mysqli_error($conn));       


        echo'<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table" table align="center">';
        echo"<tr><th>Music Title</th><th>Year</th><th>Price</th><th>Category</th></tr>"; 


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {
        $iCDID = $row['CDID'];
        $CDTitle = $row['CDTitle'];
                $CDYear = $row['CDYear'];
        $CDPrice = $row['CDPrice'];
                $CDCat = $row['catDesc'];
                $CDCatID = $row['catID'];


                echo "<tr><td>";
                echo "<a href = \"CDSelect.php?itemCode=$iCDID\">$CDTitle</a>";
                echo "</td><td>";  
                echo "<div align='center'>$CDYear</div>\n";
                echo "</td><td>";  
                echo "<div align='center'>$CDPrice </div>\n";
                echo "</td><td>";  
                echo "<div align='center'>$CDCat</div>\n";
                echo "</TD></tr>";  
    }

        echo "</table>"; 

    mysqli_free_result($queryresult); 
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

In this php it display the selected CD and editing is permitted

```
 <?php       
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');  //set the charset parameter

 include 'database_conn.php';       //make db connection

  $code = $_GET['itemCode'];        //collect form data from user input

  $sql = "SELECT nmc_cd.CDID, nmc_cd.CDTitle, nmc_cd.CDYear, nmc_cd.CDPrice, nmc_cd.catID, nmc_cd.pubID, nmc_category.catDesc, nmc_publisher.pubID, nmc_publisher.pubName
          FROM nmc_cd 
          JOIN nmc_category on (nmc_cd.catID = nmc_category.catID)
          JOIN nmc_publisher on (nmc_cd.pubID = nmc_publisher.pubID)
          WHERE nmc_cd.CDID = '$code'";                                 //link user input with primary key

  $queryresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) 
  or die (mysqli_error($conn));

  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryresult);      //function fetches result row

  $iCDID = $row['CDID'];
  $CDTitle = $row['CDTitle'];
  $CDYear = $row['CDYear'];
  $CDPrice = $row['CDPrice'];
  $CDCat = $row['catDesc'];
  $CDPub = $row['pubName'];
  $CDpubID = $row['pubID'];

    <form method="get" action="UpdateCD.php">
    <div align="center">  
    <div>Title <input type = "text" name = "CDTitle" value = "<?php echo $CDTitle; ?>" /></div></br>
    <div>Year <input type = "text" name = "CDYear" value = "<?php echo $CDYear; ?>" /></div></br>
    <div>Price <input type = "text" name = "CDPrice" value = "<?php echo $CDPrice; ?>" /></div></br>
    Category
       <select name="CDCat">
           <option value= " ">
            <?php 
            include 'database_conn.php';            //make db connection
             if (! ( is_object($conn ) && ( get_class( $conn ) == 'mysqli' ))) {
                die("DB connection failure.");
             }
             $rsCDCat = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nmc_category.catDesc FROM nmc_category");
             if ( !$rsCDCat ) {
                die("No result from DB query."); //probably invalid SQL, table error
             }
             if ( $rsCDCat->num_rows < 1 ) {  
                die("No rows returned from DB query."); //query runs but nothing is found in DB to match
             }
             while($Catcatresult = mysqli_fetch_array($rsCDCat)){
            $optioncat = "<option value='{$Catcatresult[0]}'";
            if($Catcatresult[0] == $CDCat){
            $optioncat .= " selected='selected'";
            }
            $optioncat .= ">{$Catcatresult[0]}</option>";
            echo $optioncat;
             }
             ?>
               </select></br></br>

    Publisher 
        <select name="CDPub">
           <option value= " ">
            <?php 
            include 'database_conn.php';            //make db connection
             if (! ( is_object($conn ) && ( get_class( $conn ) == 'mysqli' ))) {
                die("DB connection failure.");
             }
             $rsCDpub = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nmc_publisher.pubName FROM nmc_publisher");
             if ( !$rsCDpub ) {
                die("No result from DB query."); //probably invalid SQL, table error
             }
             if ( $rsCDpub->num_rows < 1 ) {  
                die("No rows returned from DB query."); //query runs but nothing is found in DB to match
             }
             while($Catpubresult = mysqli_fetch_array($rsCDpub)){
            $option = "<option value='{$Catpubresult[0]}'";
            if($Catpubresult[0] == $CDPub){
            $option .= " selected='selected'";
            }
            $option .= ">{$Catpubresult[0]}</option>";
            echo $option;
             }
             ?></select></br></br>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Update"></div>
    </form>
```

In this update php, it gets the values from the previous php and update the table.

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');

include 'database_conn.php';        // make db connection

  $pCDTitle = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDTitle') ? $_GET['CDTitle']: null;         // store all parameter in variable
  $pCDPubName = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDPub') ? $_GET['CDPub']: null;
  $pCDYear = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDYear') ? $_GET['CDYear']: null;
  $pCDCategory = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDCat') ? $_GET['CDCat']: null;        
  $pCDPrice = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDPrice') ? $_GET['CDPrice']: null;
  $pCDID = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDID') ? $_GET['CDID']: null;
  $pCDPubID = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'pubID') ? $_GET['pubID']: null;

  $sql = "UPDATE nmc_cd "
     . "SET nmc_cd.CDTitle='$pCDTitle',nmc_cd.CDYear='$pCDYear',nmc_cd.CDPrice='$pCDPrice',nmc_cd.catID='$pCDCategory',nmc_cd.pubID='$pCDPubName'"
     . "WHERE nmc_cd.CDID='$pCDID'";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<b><font face='verdana' font sise='3' color='red'>Record updated successfully</font></b>";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM nmc_cd "
     . "JOIN nmc_category ON (nmc_cd.catID = nmc_category.catID)"
     . "JOIN nmc_publisher ON (nmc_cd.pubID = nmc_publisher.pubID)"
     . "WHERE nmc_cd.CDID = '$pCDID'"; //Query Database
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     $CDID = $row['CDID'];
     $CDTitle = $row['CDTitle'];
     $CDYear = $row['CDYear'];
     $CDPrice = $row['CDPrice'];
     $catDesc = $row['CDCat'];
     $pubName = $row['CDPub'];
     $location = $row['location'];

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Year</th><th>Price</th><th>Catergory</th><th>Publisher</th><th>Location</th></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>".$row["CDTitle"]."</td><td> ".$row["CDYear"]."</td><td> ".$row["CDPrice"]."</td><td> ".$row["CatCD"]."</td><td> ".$row["CatPub"]."</td><td> ".$row["location"]."</td></tr>"; //Display Data Table Data
echo "</table"; 
mysqli_close($conn);
} else {
    echo "<b><font face='verdana' color='red'>Error updating record!!!</font></b>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

Comment: I see no assignments to the variables like `$pCDTitle` before the UPDATE. Is it expected?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "UPDATE nmc_cd "
     . "SET nmc_cd.CDTitle='$pCDTitle',nmc_cd.CDYear='$pCDYear',nmc_cd.CDPrice='$pCDPrice',nmc_cd.catID='$pCDCategory',nmc_cd.pubID='$pCDPubName'"
     . "WHERE nmc_cd.CDID='$pCDID'";
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "UPDATE nmc_cd "
     . "SET nmc_cd.CDTitle='$pCDTitle',nmc_cd.CDYear='$pCDYear',nmc_cd.CDPrice='$pCDPrice',nmc_cd.catID='$pCDCategory',nmc_cd.pubID='$pCDPubName' "
     . "WHERE nmc_cd.CDID='$pCDID'";
```

i.e. You are missing a SPACE character before the WHERE Clause.

(Note the end of 2nd line)

Comment: Wow you have sharp eyes. Thanks, I corrected that but still doesn't update the database.  I updated the question to show the previous 2 php which lead to Update php

Answer (score 0):

Look in the MySql logs.  Make sure bad queries are logged to the file and you should see the syntax error.  The other thing you can do is dump out the $sql string and run that in MySQL.  See if it runs successfully or not.

Comment: Thanks, SQL query shows no error. I updated the question to show the previous 2 php which lead to Update php

Comment: If the query shows no error, then it's gotta be either a connection issue or a transaction issue.  Is the database running the query through a transaction and if so, is that being committed?  The code doesn't appear to be running that way though.  The second thing then is to make sure it is connecting to the correct database with the proper credentials.

Comment: Sorry could you explain more on the committed portion ? for connecting to the database with proper credentials, yes i confirm that is correct.